# How to hide a parent div which has nested div inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-small blue">
    <span class="label bottom">Vascular Surgery</span>
</div>

<div class="btn-small red">
    <span class="label bottom">Administrator</span>
</div>

<div class="btn-small blue">
    <span class="label bottom">Cardiology North</span>
</div>

<div class="calContent">
    <div class="divContent">
        <div class="divContentHolder">
            <div>
                VASCULAR CURGERY
            </div>
            <div>
                CALENDAR GOES HERE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divContent">
        This is Second
    </div>
    <div class="divContent">
        This is Third
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/geetof8x/

If I remove the following code:

```
<div class="divContent">
    <div class="divContentHolder">
        <div>
            VASCULAR CURGERY
        </div>
        <div>
            CALENDAR GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With:

```
<div class="divContent">
    This is First
</div>
```

The script works fine but with the added extra div inside the `divContent` div, the code doesn't work correctly.

The removed code will be used in the final template. How can I edit the javascript so it can handle either case scenario.

Comment: What code doesn't work?

Comment: In the Fiddle. When you click on the first text (vacsular surgery) the content shows up. When you click on administrator or cardiology north, nothing comes up. The idea of the code is to hide the content shown and display the DIV associated with the clicked item.

Comment: Indexing the wrong elements in clcik handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only interested in the *children* (not grandchildren, etc.) of `.calContent`.

One solution is to use the [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) to limit your selection to only the direct children:

```
$('.calContent > div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').fadeOut();
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geetof8x/2/)**

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you. This is what I am looking for I believe. I will test it out. I +1 but will accept it once I did the testing :)